# why multiple variable assignment in python terminal throwing syntax error?

Tags: python

I am using python terminal and I am trying to do instantiate  multiple variable at once . It throws me an error. The code works fine in an IDE . 
Can someone helps me understand this behaviour.

```
>>> var1 =10 \
... var21 = 20 \
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    var21 = 20 \
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The backslash makes it all into one line. But it's two different statements.

Comment: That's an invalid syntax regardless of using REPL or not

Comment: Why do you even *have* those backslashes?

Comment: ok , Thanks for the suggestions. @khelwood , yes so it is all same line . Now i used the below and it worked var1 = 10 \ ;var2 = 20

Comment: Remove the backslashes. You don’t need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this, with a semicolon:

```
>>> var1 = 10;var21 = 20
```

Or use:

```
>>> var1, var21 = 10, 20
```

Comment: or with tuple assignment: `var 1, var21 = 10, 20`

Comment: ok , Thanks for the suggestions.  Now i used the below and it worked var1 = 10 \ ;var2 = 20

Comment: @rohitanand but why are you insisting on using the backslash?